# Hide Iframe Referer

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hide, referer

I have an iframe in my website pointing to an another site2. What can I do to hide my website from that site2...

I saw some javascript but I don't know where I find it...

Thank You

Comment: Sounds like you're not supposed to be using the other site's content in that way.

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers you can hide the referrer by loading a page into the iframe which uses the `refresh`-meta to redirect the page.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to mark nor flag this question as a duplicate, but I came across both of these questions on Google when looking for a solution myself and thought I would post what I found as there is now a way to accomplish this. My previous answer was deleted as a duplicate, yet the question itself was not marked as a duplicate by the user who deleted it. Since both this question and the one I link to below come up on Google I think it would be useful to others who come across this specific question to keep the answer here until one of the questions is marked as duplicate.

See my duplicate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52047736/7723415).