# Load external website in iframe but without sending HTTP_REFERER

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, http-referer

Is it possible to load an external website in iframe but without sending HTTP_REFERER ? I just don't want be tracked.

If it is possible then how and if not then is there any workaround using divs or anything else ?

For anchor tag with external link `jQuery("a").attr('rel','noreferrer');` is working, but for iframe I've failed to make it work.

Is there any script( js or jQuery ) to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple solution.
Use this in you document `<head>` tag and you are good to go :D

```
<meta name="referrer" content="none">
```

The meta referrer tag is placed in the `<head>` section of your HTML,
and references one of five states, which control how browsers send referrer information from your site.

The five states are:

1. None: Never pass referral data
2. None When Downgrade: Sends referrer information to secure HTTPS sites, but not insecure HTTP sites
3. Origin Only: Sends the scheme, host, and port (basically, the subdomain) stripped of the full URL as a referrer, i.e. `moz.com/example.html` would simply send `moz.com`
4. Origin When Cross-Origin: Sends the full URL as the referrer when the target has the same scheme, host, and port (i.e. subdomain) regardless if it's HTTP or HTTPS, while sending origin-only referral information to external sites. (note: There is a typo in the official spec. Future versions should be "origin-when-cross-origin")
5. Unsafe URL: Always passes the URL string as a referrer. Note if you have any sensitive information contained in your URL, this isn't the safest option. By default, URL fragments, username, and password are automatically stripped out.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

Comment: you probably mean `<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">`, not `none`

Comment: @user151496 No, the answer is correct. None is a permitted content, it is a void element. You can explore to the reference for details.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) stating that setting the `referrerpolicy` attribute to `no-referrer` would accomplish this.

Example:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.whatismyreferer.com/" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hello Twyx, please explain what and how your answer solves the question author's problem so they can understand it. For more information see ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @GGG I'm not really sure what more there is to explain... it's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: sorry @Twyx, I thought I had read you were using two different attributes. I apologize for the misunderstanding.